# How can I implement recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position) in recyclerView with many types of customViewHolder?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

My recycleView has 3 types of viewHolder.

Position 0 is viewHolder1.

Position 1-41 is viewHolder2.

Position 42 is viewHolder3.

but if myDataSource.size() have more than 42 it will create viewHolder3.

So I need to make recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position) working.

Please help....

this is my LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller

```
public class LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller extends LinearLayoutManager {



public LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {
    View firstVisibleChild = recyclerView.getChildAt(0);
    final int childHeight = firstVisibleChild.getHeight();

    int distanceInPixels = ((findFirstVisibleItemPosition() - position) * childHeight);
    if (distanceInPixels == 0) {
        distanceInPixels = (int) Math.abs(firstVisibleChild.getY());
    }




    SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new SmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext(), Math.abs(distanceInPixels), 1000);
    smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
    startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
}



private class SmoothScroller extends LinearSmoothScroller {
    private static final int TARGET_SEEK_SCROLL_DISTANCE_PX = 10000;
    private final float distanceInPixels;
    private final float duration;

    public SmoothScroller(Context context, int distanceInPixels, int duration) {
        super(context);
        this.distanceInPixels = distanceInPixels;
        float millisecondsPerPx = calculateSpeedPerPixel(context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        this.duration = distanceInPixels < TARGET_SEEK_SCROLL_DISTANCE_PX ?
                (int) (Math.abs(distanceInPixels) * millisecondsPerPx) : duration;
    }

    @Override
    public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
        return LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller.this
                .computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
    }

    @Override
    protected int calculateTimeForScrolling(int dx) {
        float proportion = (float) dx / distanceInPixels;
        return (int) (duration * proportion);
    }
}
```

}

and call it in activity

```
call = Quiz5Manager.getInstance(QuizGameRankingActivity.this).getQuiz5Interface().loadQuiz5Ranking(BaseApplication.sharedPreferences.getString("facebook_id", ""));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Quiz5Ranking_Model>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Quiz5Ranking_Model> call, Response<Quiz5Ranking_Model> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        Quiz5Ranking_Model quiz5Ranking_model = response.body();
                        List<Quiz5Ranking_UserRank_Model> all_rank_model = quiz5Ranking_model.getRankUsers();
                        all_rank_model.add(quiz5Ranking_model.getUserRank());
                        mAdapter = new QuizRankingAdapter(QuizGameRankingActivity.this, all_rank_model);
                        recycleview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                        recycleview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller(QuizGameRankingActivity.this));
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        recycleview.smoothScrollToPosition(20);

                        int user_rank = quiz5Ranking_model.getUserRank().getRankId();
                        if (user_rank > 44) {
                            showToast("more than 44");
                        } else {
                            if (user_rank <= 3) {
                                showToast("Top 3");
                            } else if (user_rank >= 4 && user_rank <= 44) {
                                showToast("Normal");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Quiz5Ranking_Model> call, Throwable t) {
                showToast("Fail to load. Please try again later.");
            }
        });
```

And I got null pointer exception on this line

```
View firstVisibleChild = recyclerView.getChildAt(0);
```

Comment: You have not provided any errors you are facing. if you want your problem to be resolved, please add your problem with some information about errors. Otherwise, syntax is already Good.

Comment: I already updated my post.

Comment: Can u show me the example?

Comment: did you read my answer below?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54899300/8144663

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use **custom smooth scroller,** while you can already use a **default** one. And also **avoid** initialising adaptor after callback. initialise it in on create with blank arraylist, and then **update data into adapter**, this will be a good practice, or else adaptor will be initialised in each and **every api callback**.

Also you will need to do a post run to smooth scroll in post frame like,

```
recyclerview.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 recycleview.smoothScrollToPosition(20);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SmoothScroller` with the preference `SNAP_TO_START`:

```
RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(context) {
  @Override protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
    return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_START;
  }
};
```

Now set the position where you want to scroll to:

```
smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
```

and pass that `SmoothScroller` to the `LayoutManager`:

```
layoutManager.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
```

**Update**

Remove these two line from `onResponse` and add them in `onCreate`

```
 recycleview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
 recycleview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManagerWithSmoothScroller(QuizGameRankingActivity.this));
```

This is not good practice to set adapter again and again

Comment: i already tried this but it is not working. I think because i have many types of customViewHolder